# How can I center Flashcards vertically, but not horizontally?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, flashcards

I'm currently experimenting with flashcards (the learning technique as well as the LaTeX document class) and [`flashcards`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex2e/contrib/flashcards) seems to be pretty nice.

But I could not find an option to center my flashcards vertically, but not horizontally:

[image: ugly horizontal centering]

When I have the content of the flashcards within a `theorem` environment, the horizontal centering is not there (which is good), but as you can see in the flashcard at the upper right, I don't have much space. `theorem` wastes space by putting "definition" or something similar at the top and indenting the content.

## Question

How can I use the flashcards document class and center vertically, but not horizontally?

## MWE

The following code was used to create the image from above:

### mwe.tex

```
\documentclass[mycards,frame]{flashcards}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}% math symbols / fonts
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % this is needed for correct output of umlauts in pdf
\usepackage{enumitem}

\def\mdr{\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Bild}{Bild}

\begin{document}
\begin{flashcard}{ Tangentialebene }
{
    Sei $S \subseteq \mdr^3$ eine reguläre Fläche, $s \in S$,
    $F: U \rightarrow V \cap S$ eine lokale Parametrisierung um $s$
    (d.~h. $s \in V$)
    \[(u,v) \mapsto (x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v))\]
    Für $p=F^{-1}(s) \in U$ sei
    \[        J_F(u,v) = \begin{pmatrix}
            \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} (p) & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} (p)\\
            \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} (p) & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} (p)\\
            \frac{\partial z}{\partial u} (p) & \frac{\partial z}{\partial v} (p)
        \end{pmatrix}\]
    und $D_P F: \mdr^2 \rightarrow \mdr^3$ die durch $J_F (p)$
    definierte lineare Abbildung.

    Dann heißt $T_s S := \Bild(D_p F)$ die \textbf{Tangentialebene}
    an $s \in S$.
 }
\end{flashcard}

\begin{flashcard}{ Normalenfeld\\Fläche, orientierbare }
{
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
        \item Ein \textbf{Normalenfeld} auf der
              Fläche $S$ ist eine Abbildung $n: S \rightarrow S^2 \subseteq \mdr^3$
              mit $n(s) \in T_s S^\perp$ für jedes $s \in S$.
        \item $S$ heißt \textbf{orientierbar},
              wenn es ein stetiges Normalenfeld auf $S$ gibt.
    \end{enumerate}
 }
\end{flashcard}

\begin{flashcard}{ Normalenkrümmung }
{
    In der Situation aus XY heißt die Krümmung $\kappa_\gamma(0)$
    der Kurve $\gamma$ in der Ebene $(s+ E)$ im Punkt $s$ die
    \textbf{Normalenkrümmung}\footnotemark von $S$ in $s$ in Richtung
    $x = \gamma'(0)$.

    Man scheibt: $\kappa_\gamma(0) := \kappa_{\text{Nor}}(s, x)$
 }
\end{flashcard}
\end{document}
```

### mycards.cfg

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]
\ProvidesFile{avery5388.cfg}
\newcommand{\cardpaper}{a4paper}
\newcommand{\cardpapermode}{portrait}
\newcommand{\cardrows}{4}
\newcommand{\cardcolumns}{2}
\setlength{\cardheight}{70mm}
\setlength{\cardwidth}{100mm}
\setlength{\topoffset}{2mm}
\setlength{\oddoffset}{5mm}
\setlength{\evenoffset}{5mm}
\endinput
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `\center` from the definition of `\flashcards@ps@back@begin@plain` (or replace `\center` with `\raggedright`).

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mycards.cfg}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]
\ProvidesFile{avery5388.cfg}
\newcommand{\cardpaper}{a4paper}
\newcommand{\cardpapermode}{portrait}
\newcommand{\cardrows}{4}
\newcommand{\cardcolumns}{2}
\setlength{\cardheight}{70mm}
\setlength{\cardwidth}{100mm}
\setlength{\topoffset}{2mm}
\setlength{\oddoffset}{5mm}
\setlength{\evenoffset}{5mm}
\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[mycards,frame]{flashcards}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}% math symbols / fonts
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % this is needed for correct output of umlauts in pdf
\usepackage{enumitem}

\def\mdr{\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Bild}{Bild}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\flashcards@ps@back@begin@plain}
%    {\vspace*{\fill}\center\flashcards@format@back}% REMOVED
    {\vspace*{\fill}\flashcards@format@back}% ADDED
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{flashcard}{ Tangentialebene }
{
    Sei $S \subseteq \mdr^3$ eine reguläre Fläche, $s \in S$,
    $F: U \rightarrow V \cap S$ eine lokale Parametrisierung um $s$
    (d.~h. $s \in V$)
    \[(u,v) \mapsto (x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v))\]
    Für $p=F^{-1}(s) \in U$ sei
    \[        J_F(u,v) = \begin{pmatrix}
            \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} (p) & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} (p)\\
            \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} (p) & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} (p)\\
            \frac{\partial z}{\partial u} (p) & \frac{\partial z}{\partial v} (p)
        \end{pmatrix}\]
    und $D_P F: \mdr^2 \rightarrow \mdr^3$ die durch $J_F (p)$
    definierte lineare Abbildung.

    Dann heißt $T_s S := \Bild(D_p F)$ die \textbf{Tangentialebene}
    an $s \in S$.
 }
\end{flashcard}

\begin{flashcard}{ Normalenfeld\\Fläche, orientierbare }
{
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
        \item Ein \textbf{Normalenfeld} auf der
              Fläche $S$ ist eine Abbildung $n: S \rightarrow S^2 \subseteq \mdr^3$
              mit $n(s) \in T_s S^\perp$ für jedes $s \in S$.
        \item $S$ heißt \textbf{orientierbar},
              wenn es ein stetiges Normalenfeld auf $S$ gibt.
    \end{enumerate}
 }
\end{flashcard}

\begin{flashcard}{ Normalenkrümmung }
{
    In der Situation aus XY heißt die Krümmung $\kappa_\gamma(0)$
    der Kurve $\gamma$ in der Ebene $(s+ E)$ im Punkt $s$ die
    \textbf{Normalenkrümmung}\footnotemark von $S$ in $s$ in Richtung
    $x = \gamma'(0)$.

    Man scheibt: $\kappa_\gamma(0) := \kappa_{\text{Nor}}(s, x)$
 }
\end{flashcard}
\end{document}
```

[image]